# React - Passing value between components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-table, state

I'm practicing React by trying to solve a puzzle. If anyone could help me get a bit further, I would appreciate it.

Essentially I have two components, an input and a table. The input should be a number to place in the bottom-left cell of a table, it starts with a number N and increments by X from LTR then up. I will later want to let the user increment RTL, but I'm focusing for now on just getting the table and input interacting.

For the input element I have this:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jZYKQJ

```js
class NForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {valueOfN: ''};

    this.handleChangeOfN = this.handleChangeOfN.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({valueOfN: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          N:
          <input type="text" value={this.state.valueOfN} onChange={this.handleChangeOfN} />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <NameForm />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<div id=table-component>Loading...</div>
```

Then getting the table element to even get the value of N is where I am stuck. 
I've tried a couple different datatables, including one from a tutorial https://flaviocopes.com/react-spreadsheet/ and trying to strip it down to its most basic element. I think I would get a bit further if I could pass the value of N from the NForm Element to my table.

```js
import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react'

import {
  Table,
  TableRow,
  TableRowColumn,
  TableBody
} from 'material-ui/Table';

export default class MagicTableReact extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log(this.props);
    this.state = {
      data : [{id:0,name:"joe"},{id:1,name:"john"},{id:2,name:"Brad"},{id:3,name:"Jack"},{id:4,name:"Andrew"}],
      height: '300px',
      width: '20px',
      valueOfN: '',
      valueOfX : '',
      valueOfM : '',
      valueOfW : '',
    };
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div  className="col-sm-3">
        <div>
          <h1>Table</h1>
          <Table
            valueOfN={this.state.valueOfN}
            valueOfX={this.state.valueOfX}
          >
            <TableBody
            >
              {this.state.data.map((user, i) =>
                <TableRow key={i}>
                  <TableRowColumn>{i+1}</TableRowColumn>
                  <TableRowColumn>{i+2}</TableRowColumn>
                  <TableRowColumn>{i+2}</TableRowColumn>
                  <TableRowColumn>{this.valueOfN}</TableRowColumn>

                </TableRow>
              )}
            </TableBody>
          </Table>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

MagicTableReact.propTypes = {

};
```

Does anyone know why my table isn't receiving valueOfN

Comment: Its should be `this.state.valueOfN `

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN it doesn't work even if I change it to this.state.valueOfN

Comment: your components appear to be entirely separate; how are you _trying_ to communicate state changes between them?

Comment: shouldn't you be render one component in the other and the parent component passes down props that will handle the changes, that is how you can get your state up to the parent component through props, if it is the other way around you could just pass down the `valueOfN` as a prop to the table and display them with `this.props.valueOfN`..